# rChart nPlot questions on default 'toggles' and additional variables from the dataset included in the tooltip

Tags: r, rcharts

I have the following plot:

```
df <- data.frame(var = letters[1:26], count = sample(1:300, 26),
                 label = sample(toupper(letters[1:5]), 26, replace = T))
library(rCharts)
p4 <- nPlot(count ~ var, data = df, type = 'pieChart',
            width = 500, height=500)
p4$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(x, y){ 
  return 'Type: ' + x + '<br>Count: ' + y 
} !#")
p4
```

By default all of the levels of `var` are shown, and the menu at the top allows you to toggle each level of `var` on and off.

My question is: Is there a way to set a default other than 'all on'? For example, when the plot is loaded, I'd like only four levels of `var` to be on: `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, as having all of them at once is a bit of a blast to the senses.

Is this possible?

A second question: I'd like to also include in the tooltip each levels value of `label`.

I tried things such as:

```
p4$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(x, y, label){ 
  return 'Type: ' + x + '<br>Count: ' + y + '<br>Label: ' + label
} !#")
```

along with including label as a grouping variable, etc. But I can't seem to get it to work correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: don't know about your first question, the second should be `+ '<br>Label: ' + data.label` passing data to the function instead of label, is that what you want?

Comment: When I do that, I end up getting the entry for `var` showing up again under `label`.

Comment: Label should show `df$label`, but instead it is showing `df$var`, the same as 'Type'